# Azure Function App Service Bus Trigger Connection String from appSettings.json

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Below is a function based on Azure Service Bus Trigger:

```
[Function(nameof(DocumentInboundProcessor))]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%DocUploadQueueName%", Connection = 
"%DocUploadAzureServiceBusConnectionString%")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
```

I know that having these settings in local.settings.json will work locally.

In the Production and Testing Environment that is on Azure how do we get to read these values from appsettings.json. Typically we store all application settings in appsettings.json and read from appsettings.json. How do I get the above two variables work from appSettings.json in Server.

Comment: You'll need to set those up as environment variable in your Function App.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Sean Feldman that, you need to store values in Environment variables section of Function app and then you can  use them as below:

[image]

**`Code`** which worked with above settings:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp130
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(queueName:"%queuename%", Connection = "rithcon")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogCritical("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogCritical("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]